# Setting the project root

Tags: php

On my dev server my directory structure is:

```
XAMPP
    >htdocs
        >my project
```

On my live server it's

```
www
```

I want to be able to grab the project's directory regardless of the directory structure. So, in the dev environment, I want to find `my project` and in the live environment, simply `www`.

I've tried

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/connect.php');
```

and it works on the live server, but on the dev server I get this error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/inc/connect.php'
```

So, that tells me `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'` is `C:/xampp/htdocs` on the dev server, but I need `C:/xampp/htdocs/my project`

How can I always find the project root regardless of the server?

Comment: Perhaps a better question might be "How can I set XAMPP's document root?", for your dev server?

Comment: define('ROOT', 'your path') depending on your cases and then require(ROOT.'/inc/connect.php') is one of the many solutions. This one is quick

Comment: @Psychokiller1888 - So, where do I define the constant?

Comment: you surely include in your project at the begining something like constant.class.php or config.class.php or common.class.php so use them to hold your constants

Comment: You could try getcwd() on your loader script. That should give you the directory where the script is running from. That said, if you want to use DOCUMENT_ROOT you should set DocumentRoot to C:/xampp/htdocs/my project instead in your XAMPP's httpd.conf. That's the value DOCUMENT_ROOT gets.

Comment: Locate `httpd.conf` file on your XAMPP like `../xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf`
Go to `DocumentRoot`Line and change your current path with that what you want. 
E.g. `../xampp/htdocs` to `../xampp/htdocs/my_project`. Restart XAMPP and have fun :)

Comment: @EduardoRomero @rcro What about multiple projects in XAMPP? If I change the `httpd.conf` file, won't that affect all other projects?

Comment: It would affect everything. I guess then you're not using the correct approach (using `DOCUMENT_ROOT`). Either define a constant from `__FILE__` `getcwd()` `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` or something similar. You would need to do so in a script that's loaded on every page you need the constant.

Optionally, you can create a vhost per project (I do that). Each project gets its own DocumentRoot/DOCUMENT_ROOT. There's usually an example under `apache/conf/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf`. It's a bit more work but I like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic constant `__FILE__` to get the absolute path of the script file. Be warned that the constant will always point to the absolute path to the file that has the code, so if you run `index.php` and `require include/reusable.php`, using `__FILE__` constant inside reusable.php will give absolute path to the include/reusable.php file and not the index.php file.

[MagicConstants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#language.constants.predefined)